# Assign post category to a page by selecting category from page dashboard

Tags: categories, page-specific-settings

I'd like users to be able to assign a category to a page by selecting from the page dashboard. So when they create a new page they can select the post category they want to be linked and display on that page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

add this code into functions.php and a taxonomy box will be created for page from where user can make categories for page.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'genre',
        'page',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: What I meant was to choose an existing category from the posts section on the page that you want to assign the posts category too.

Comment: for that you just has to change genre term with category. and that's it.